# How to eliminate the gap between top header items in Avada theme

Tags: css

I'm trying to find out the CSS code that's causing 1px gap between the items in top header.

Here's the website: http://youleadyou.net

The top header is the blue menu with items: Home, About, Contact, Login.

I want to remove the gap between the items. I can't find it anywhere on the internet and I can't find any CSS class which can cause this to happen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "border-left: 1px solid transparent" from ".fusion-secondary-menu > ul > li" in line 5435

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot dude.